# AngularUI - Bootstrap - $uibModal bindToController

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Can someone please provide a clear explanation and simple example of what the 'bindToController' option actually does when using $uibModal. I'm creating modals specifying both a controller and controllerAs name. Thanks!

Comment: https://toddmotto.com/no-scope-soup-bind-to-controller-angularjs/ should probably help you understand the 'bindToController' concept with examples. 
InShort: 'bindToController' will help you bind your isolate bindings directly to 'controllerAs' object instead of $scope object.

Comment: Thanks! I had actually read through that before. I think I understand the idea of binding the isolate scope directly to the controllerAs object when dealing with directives. But when using $uibModal I guess I'm confused as to what scope exactly is being bound to the controller. Are we dealing with an isolate scope here?

Comment: By default, a $uibModal creates an isolated scope. 

However, if you want the parent scope to be maintained, you can declare with scope property in the uibmodal options. And if you also add 'bindToController' in the options, then the parent scope object might get attached to the controllerAs object. This is what inferred from the [bootstrap angular] (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#uibmodal).